# What affects the score MySQL gives returned results when using fulltext indexes?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Ok, I am using the below query to do a fulltext query search:

```
SELECT city,state_prefix FROM zip_code3 WHERE MATCH (zip_code,city,state_prefix,state_full) AGAINST ('birmingham al') LIMIT 1;
```

Now, on my development server this works like a treat, rows with the city as "Birmingham" and the state as "AL" are given the highest scores, that being `9.7016019821167` and another similar record with the same city but from a different state of "IA" is given a score of `5.988482475280762`.

However, on the production server it is totally different, both results have an equal score of `6.05505323410034`.

This is causing chaos as I only need the first result and that result needs to be the correct city/state.

So I'm wondering why am I getting different results and why does the production servers scoring seem to be out of whack?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to know what the problem is without seeing your config files, so I'll try my best guess.

I think the problem is with [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). The default value is 4, so probably your production server is set to the default and ignores the state.

Comment: Ok, finally got that changed to `2` but there was no change, everything still has the same score. What kind of config options do you need to see?

Comment: @Brett That was my only guess.